# phone number validation with only one "+" character in first place

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to check following number in regex expressions,

> +78645435748675
>
> 87978976435

Not valid below

> +944+4814674
>
> 464641+
>
> 4+167464165

Comment: You didn't specified number of digits in phone number?

Comment: You can use `/^\+?\d+$/`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to actually include what you have actually tried so far. Don't just rely on "I want".

Comment: Is the `+` optional in the fourteen digit sequence? But @evolutionxbox is right. You need to include more details and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @rock321987 : number of digits not important but "+" sign should come only once and only in first character

Comment: then see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
^\+?\d+$
```

```js
var regex = /^\+?\d+$/;

var phoneNumbers = ['+78645435748675', '87978976435', '+944+4814674', '464641+', '4+167464165'];

phoneNumbers.forEach(function(number) {
  document.writeln(number.match(regex) + '<br>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. `\+?` optional matching for the `+` in fourteen-digit `\d{14}` numbers.
2. `\d{11}` matches eleven sequential digits.
3. You will not match other number of digits this way.
4. If `+` is not optional, simply remove the `?`.

```js
var regex = /^\+?\d{14}$|^\d{11}$/;

var phoneNumbers = ['+78645435748675', '87978976435', '+944+4814674', '464641+', '4+167464165'];

phoneNumbers.forEach(function(number) {
  alert(number.match(regex));
});
```